# Объявление закольцованных функций в Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Допустим есть функций `PROCESS_OPERATOR` и `PROCESS_WHERE`. В теле `PROCESS_OPERATOR` вызывает функцию `PROCESS_WHERE`, а та вызывает опять `PROCESS_OPERATOR` для рекурсивного обхода XML. При попытке создать эти функции вылетают ошибки

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'PROCESS_WHERE' must be declared
```

в функции `PROCESS_OPERATOR` и

```
PLS-00905: object SYS.PROCESS_OPERATOR is invalid
```

в функции `PROCESS_WHERE`.

Есть ли вариант, как их можно объявить?

Comment: Почему объект создаётся в схеме SYS?

Comment: Взаимно-вызывающие функции в оракле можно создать только если одна из них (или обе) лежат в пакете.